# Identifier 'userInfo' has already been declared in React-native

Tags: react-native

When I run my react-native code it's says "Identifier 'userInfo' has already been declared". How can I solve that?

I want to get the username and password from user and then I check with the existing admin and 1234 username and password.

```js
import { userInfo } from 'os'; //libraries 
import { CreateSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

const userInfo = {username: 'admin', password: '1234'};
class loginScreen extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state= {username: '', password:''}
   }

<TextInput  style={styles.input}
            placeholder='Username'
            onChangeText={(username=> this.setState( {username}))}
            value={this.state.username}
/>

<TextInput  style={styles.input}
            placeholder='Password'
            onChangeText={(password=> this.setState( {password}))}
            value={this.state.password}
/>

<TouchableOpacity
             style={styles.btnEnter}  
             onPress={this._signin}
>
    <Text style={styles.btnEnterText}> Enter</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? my answer should help

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `userInfo` declarations. One from `os` and the other where you're declaring your `userInfo` constant.

Just name your constant something else:

```
const userCredentials = {username: 'admin', password: '1234'};
```